# Variance of a non-stationary version of an MA

Tags: time-series, self-study, variance, arima, moving-average

Given the following stochastic process:

$$ y_t = \sum_{i=1}^n(\beta\epsilon_{i-1}+\epsilon_i) ~~~~~,~~\epsilon\sim WN(0,\sigma^2)$$

the solution says that $\text{Var}(y_t)=\sigma^2[n(1+\beta^2)+2(n-1)\beta]$, but I obtained a different result. My procedure is the following.

First of all $E[y_t]=0$, then:

$$ \text{Var}(y_t) = E[(y_t-E[y_t])^2] = E[(y_t)^2] $$
$$ = E[(\sum_{i=1}^n(\beta\epsilon_{i-1}+\epsilon_i))^2]=E[\sum_{i=1}^n(\beta\epsilon_{i-1}+\epsilon_i)^2+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n(\beta\epsilon_{i-1}+\epsilon_i)(\beta\epsilon_{j-1}+\epsilon_j)] $$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^nE[\beta^2\epsilon_{i-1}^2+\epsilon_i^2+2\beta\epsilon_{i-1}\epsilon_i]+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^nE[(\beta\epsilon_{j-1}\epsilon_i]$$
$$ =\sigma^2n[(1+\beta^2)+2(n-1)\beta] $$

Is it correct my way and my result? It may seem that the difference between the two results is difference but it depends in two different ways to tackle the square of the summation.

Comment: You have time indices $t$, $i$, and $n$. I think you need to fix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second to last line is equal to the provided answer in your solutions, not your last line.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^nE[\beta^2\epsilon_{i-1}^2+\epsilon_i^2+2\beta\epsilon_{i-1}\epsilon_i]+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^nE[(\beta\epsilon_{j-1}\epsilon_i] &= \sum_i \left[\beta^2 \sigma^2 + \sigma^2 \right] +2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\beta E[\epsilon_i \epsilon_{i} ] \\
&= \sum_i \left[\beta^2 \sigma^2 +  \sigma^2 \right] + 2  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\beta \sigma^2 \\
&= n\sigma^2(\beta^2+1) + 2 (n-1)\sigma^2\beta \\
&= \sigma^2[n(1+\beta^2)+2(n-1)\beta] \\
&\neq \sigma^2n[(1+\beta^2)+2(n-1)\beta]
\end{align*}

Comment: interesting refreshment of arithmetics for me :) I was just wondering by what rule have you come to the inner of the double sum expressed as E(beta*eps(j-1)*eps(i)) suddenly

Comment: @King'sSolomonHorse for any $i$, $\epsilon_i$ is only correlated with $\epsilon_{j-1}$ when $j = i+1$. This is because the $\epsilon$s are white. Also, thanks for the question, because it helped me catch a typo.

Comment: I do not understand why you in the first line pass from a double summation to a simple one.

Comment: @Archimede for the same reason in the comment above. Another way of saying why is because $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+2}^n E[\epsilon_i \epsilon_{j-1}] = 0$. If you think of a matrix of all the covariances between the epsilons, these are all the terms that are more than $1$ away from the diagonal.